# Copying code blocks in Windows

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Recently when I copy code blocks from answers and questions, the end of line characters are not being copied too. This means that everything is copied in one line, and this can cause problems when being parsed. The only work around is to copy and paste each line separately, which can be tedious for large blocks.

I'm using IE7 in Windows, which may be the culprit, but it didn't used to be an issue.

Comment: I don't really have any ideas, although if possible, I suggest chrome.  It's a better browser in my experience.

Comment: Would if I could, stuck with IE7 at work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you're experiencing this because we don't provide support for IE7 anymore. You can see [which browsers we officially support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) at that link.

I urge you to, if your office is STILL using IE7, to suggest they upgrade due to security concerns and an increased lack of compatibility Internet-wide.

Comment: Unfortunately those arguments fall on deaf ears. We have since been moved to IE8, which is better, but not greatly so and this problem still persists.